# Kubernetes fails to create loadbalancer on gce. Required 'compute.instances.list' permission

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

When I try to expose a deployment on kubernetes using

`kubectl expose deployment NAME --target-port=80 --type=LoadBalancer`

I see the following error when I run

`kubectl describe service/NAME`

*Error creating load balancer (will retry): Failed to create load balancer for service default/NAME: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.instances.list' permission for 'projects/PROJECT_NAME', forbidden*

In the above PROJECT_NAME corresponds to my GCP project name.

Looking in the console GCE i see that the kubernetes instance is using the default service account. I checked the roles of the service account and it said "Editor", i tried adding the compute instance admin role. It didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you create your cluster? Did you just use `kube-up.sh`? Or kubeadm? Did you set any special environment variables or flags? Are you running from a specific release or from the head of github?

Comment: I just created one through google-container-engine.

Comment: If you could send me your project and cluster name I can take a look. robertbailey at google.com.

Comment: @RobertBailey I think that the problem was that I somehow lost the API account in GCP. I created a new project and cluster and now i seems to work.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix it.